# Is it possible to create an instance of an application server in the cloud?

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, ibm-was-oc

I'm new to Bluemix, but fairly skilled in WebSphere Application Server. I recently heard colleagues discussing the potential of IBM hosting an app server in the cloud. I saw this [Beta announcement](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/07/14/beta-ibm-application-server-on-cloud/) and was wondering how long the beta will last and if there's an actual product/service available.

Answer (score 2):

The beta program for Application Server on Cloud has ended.  Planned GA is Sept 24.  Here is the announcement:

- [IBM Application Server on Cloud is extended to Bluemix, which enables simple, repeatable, and quick deployments of WebSphere Application Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?subtype=ca&infotype=an&appname=iSource&supplier=897&letternum=ENUS215-439)

After GA, you'll find the service icon in the Bluemix catalog in the Web and Application category.

Answer (score 2):

The IBM Application Server on Cloud is generally available and you can learn more at:  https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/application-server-on-cloud/

We'd love to hear from you on the forums with your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Not only can you provision the latest versions of WebSphere Application Server Liberty profile and WebSphere Application Server classic (aka full profile or traditional WebSphere Application Server), now you can also get an early look at the next release with the WebSphere Application Server classic V9 beta. You can provision a virtual machine with an instance of WebSphere Application Server v9 beta running in Bluemix.  Details on this open beta are available in the WebSphere Early Programs website:

https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/iwmdocs/web/cc/earlyprograms/websphere/wasob/index.shtml

Or get a quick overview by watching this video Introducing the WAS classic V9 beta:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ssYKjcIRX8